# query a firebase collection returns less number of documents sometimes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase query is returning sometimes only 1 document when there are exactly 2 documents all the time in the database.
I even checked manually.

But the following code sometimes returns 2 and sometimes only 1.
Any idea why this is happening???

My code is:

```js
  const pages = await getDocs(query(collection(db, `sites`, siteId, `pages`)));
  console.log(
    `pages.docs`,
    pages.docs.map((d) => d.id),
    siteId
  );
```

Screen Recording Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPiHjJoioBc

[image: Fi]

Comment: You should share the contents of the database so we can also see everything you're seeing and reproduce the results. Firestore doesn't return incorrect query results (that would be pretty bad for any database, right?) - usually the problem is with data itself, or the expectations of the person performing the query. You also haven't explained what you're doing to generate so many log lines here when there is only one log line in your code.

Comment: i'm running the function multiple times, to show that SOMETIMES it returns only 1 page, instead of all.

Comment: @DougStevenson here is a screen recording https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPiHjJoioBc

Comment: It looks like those log entries always fire in pairs: first a line with only one document, then the line with both of them. What is the (write) operation triggering the logging? Does that operation run on the same system?

Comment: that is just a bug in my code in useEffect, but I'm curious how it could return incorrect results sometimes! it should always return all the documents from the collection, right?

Comment: Also, there is another operation in my application that (might be) updating the document that is missing while it is being fetched. but in any case this should affect the read results, if I'm correct?

Comment: You can implement strategies like using real-time listeners `onSnapshot` instead of queries to ensure you receive immediate updates, implementing proper error handling and retry mechanisms, and structuring your data and operations in a way that minimizes conflicts and race conditions.